# General equilibrium effects of affirmative action policies

Tags: reference-request, labor-economics, education-economics, discrimination

I am interested in the debate about affirmative action in college admissions and I would be happy to read some theoretical economic investigations of the effects of these policies. I would be glad if someone could point out a good and recent survey of this literature, or some papers addressing this issue. The following two questions are of particular interest to me:

- the general equilibrium effects of affirmative action (say, in college admissions) on labor market outcomes (acquisition of human capital, wage differentials, etc.)
- the welfare analysis of affirmative action policies, with some discussion of the appropriate social welfare criterion (e.g., fairness vs efficiency)

Any reference would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one survey which corresponds to what I was looking for: *Theories of Statistical Discrimination and Affirmative Action: A Survey* by Hamming Fang and Andrea Moro, in the *Handbook of Social Economics* (2011 edition).